# How can an input and output show linked in BizTalk and not have a connection?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I need to add an extra field to a BizTalk service call.
I added the field as an element in the input and output schemas.
Then I was going to map the input and output in the mapper.
But I was faced with this:

[image: MapperInput]

[image: MapperOutput]

The old fields show as linked and they are working. But there's no visible link. I would like to add the new field and map it the same way and not link it directly.

Anyone knows how this can be linked?

I searched for the old fields in the solution and I couldn't find anything that could explain this. I guess there must be some property I don't know about but I don't see anything either.

Answer (score 0):

The link is done in another page. I forgot you can scroll through pages in biztalk mapper [image: Pages]

Comment: Also, if you select a node that's linked on another page, that tab will show an exclamation mark.